# issue with joins and not exist values

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Here is my table looks..

Users

```
Id  name    height  weight
1   aaa     1       10
2   bbb     4       104
3   ccc     1       10
4   ddd     56      150
5   eee     232     180
```

second table looks like

Profile view

```
Id  sender  receiver    block
1   1       2           True
2   2       3           False
3   4       1           False
```

The problem i am facing is,,When I search using **height** and **weight** in **users** table and **block** using **profileview** table.I couldn't get proper results..

If second user **bbb** search with height "1" and weight "10" it should be appear **3rd user details ccc** .First user also matched but First user blocked second user.The problem is when i using join values coming if sender and receiver exists i the profileview table.If not exist how do we do in joins..

Comment: `mysql` or `SQL-Server` (MS) ?  What have you tried so far.

Comment: What is it that you're asking? It's also a vague question.

Comment: SELECT  a.* FROM users a join profileview b on
((a.id = b.sender and b.receiver = '105' and b.block = 'False')  or
        ( not(a.id = b.sender and b.receiver = '105'))) 
where (a.height between 1 and 65) this sql i tried..Now it is coming both results..

Comment: sqlserver (MS)..

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Users
(
    Id          int,
    [Name]      varchar(255),
    Height      int,
    [Weight]    int
)

CREATE TABLE #ProfileView
(
    Id          int,
    Sender      int,
    Receiver    int,
    [Block]     varchar(5)
)

INSERT INTO #Users
    (Id, [Name], Height, [Weight])
VALUES
    (1, 'aaa', 1, 10),
    (2, 'bbb', 4, 104),
    (3, 'ccc', 1, 10),
    (4, 'ddd', 56, 150),
    (5, 'eee', 232, 180)

INSERT INTO #ProfileView
        (Id, Sender, Receiver, [Block])
VALUES  
    (1, 1, 2, 'True'),
    (2, 2, 3, 'False'),
    (3, 4, 1, 'False')

DECLARE
    @CallingUser int,   --User performing the search
    @Height int,        --Height searched for
    @Weight int         --Weight searched for

SET @CallingUser = 2
SET @Height = 1
SET @Weight = 10

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Users
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #ProfileView
        ON #Users.Id = #ProfileView.Id
            AND #ProfileView.Receiver = @CallingUser
WHERE
    #Users.Id <> @CallingUser
    AND #Users.Height = @Height
    AND #Users.[Weight] = @Weight
    AND (#ProfileView.[Block] = 'False' OR #ProfileView.[Block] IS NULL)

DROP TABLE #Users
DROP TABLE #ProfileView
```